# Why does my mesh get distorted when switching from edit to object mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode, distort

Whenever I create adjustments to a mesh in edit mode (covering body with clothes for example), when I switch back into object mode the mesh distorts weirdly as shown below and shoots out in all directions at a random point in the mesh:

[image]

Why does this keep happening when I switch from edit to object mode and how can I stop/ revert it without deleting what I just edited (happened at least 4 times now)?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking exactly. What does "this" mean in your question? Can you explain what is happening in a more elaborate, objective way?

Comment: Whenever I create adjustments to a mesh in edit mode (covering body with clothes for example), when I change back into object mode the mesh distorts weirdly as shown above and shoots out in all directions at a random point in the mesh. Could it possibly be that I may have had the Ctrl + R cuts done too many times in too little a space?

Comment: This really sounds strange, and could have many reasons. In this case, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it.

Comment: It maybe that you have a Modifier(s) with Preview turned off in Edit Mode.

Comment: Could be modifiers, could be shape keys.

Comment: In my case it was due to shape keys. Remove the shape keys and mesh is good in object mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated, Z-grabbed and separated a "shin-loop" from a *Make Human*,  built it into a boot shape (I wanted to keep the vertex groups for weight painting). When I changed to object mode the mesh completely distorted.

Looking at the shape keys under *Mesh* I unticked the *Relative* check box - this seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old thread, but for others looking for an answer, like I was yesterday, i found there was a simple reason in my case.

I had let animation play for a few seconds to see how physics would would affect the character's clothing. If I switched into edit mode and then into any other mode without resetting the animation to frame 1, the clothing would deform into a crumpled mess around the shins.

Just remember to return to frame 1 before going into edit mode